# How to implement custom login/logout (Authentication) inside Spring MVC when you have separate Auth Server which user Password Grant

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0

I am currently working on a Spring MVC web application which calls separate AuthServer (resource owner password credentials). My question is it ok for the Spring MVC web app to implement and handle its own login interface while it needs to be integrated with the separate AuthServer. Any idea on how to handle it using Spring Security? I wonder if is it possible to put authentication (OAuth password grant) in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. BTW, AuthServer is on the same server but different application, not on a separate server like Facebook or Google AuthServer.
I have done my research but did not found an answer on the possibility. Hope someone could help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question ? Do you want to implement a custom login page with third party Oauth2 server using password grant ?

Comment: My question if it is ok and how to implement it correctly using Spring Security. I already have my custom login page that calls the 3rd party AuthServer (same server) but the logout is not yet being handled. I'll try the suggestion of @gen.Strash

Comment: It's perfectly alright to have a custom login page with `Password` grant. However you have to be careful about not sending the user's credentials to your own server, instead use Javascript to get token on the client side using the `clientId + clientSecret + username + password`. Since in this case `clientId` and `clientSecret` are on the client side, you can set `clientSecret` to be empty. Which is a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented such a thing. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it is maybe the fastest. So in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`- authenticate method - just work with your other authorization server and handle the exceptions there- you can wrap the other server responses and exceptions with your own corresponding to your structure. That worked for me.